# how does copyTo in opencv c++ works?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have gone through the below snippet and was wondering how `copyTo() in opencv` function work.

```
 // Make a copy
 Mat faceWithGlassesNaive1 = faceImage.clone();
 // Take the eye region from the image
 Mat roiFace =  faceWithGlassesNaive1(Range(150,250),Range(140,440));
 // Replace the eye region with the sunglass image
 glassBGR.copyTo(roiFace);
```

Does `copyTo()` work on `copyByreference`, so that any modifications done to `roiface` gets reflected in `faceWithGlassesNaive1`? Or Am i missing something ?. Need help .

1. Below is the faceimage

[image: faceimage]

2. Below is the glassBGR Image 
   [image]
3. Below is the output of `glassBGR.copyTo(roiFace)` from the above snippet
   [image]

Comment: I think your expectation is wrong from the ```copyTo()``` function, please check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77) You can achieve it with a simple algorithm with your own code. You can also check [this](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/overlay-transparent-image-in-opencv.html)

Answer (score 1):

`copyTo` function of opencv as the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a626fe5f96d02525e2604d2ad46dd574f) says:

> The method copies the matrix data to another matrix.

So you can not expect to achieve your task like that but you can simply achieve it as an approach like this:

The code:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat faceImage = imread("/ur/face/image/directory/elon.jpg");
    Mat glassBGR = imread("/ur/glass/image/directory/glass.png");

    resize(glassBGR,glassBGR,Size(300,100));
    // check each pixel of glass and if its white(255,255,255) then change it with face image pixels
    for(int i=0;i<glassBGR.cols;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<glassBGR.rows;j++)
        {
            if(!(glassBGR.at<Vec3b>(j, i) == Vec3b(255,255,255)))
            {
                faceImage.at<Vec3b>(j+150,i+140) = glassBGR.at<Vec3b>(j, i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    imshow("result",faceImage);
    waitKey(0);        
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a manual implementation of copyTo using a mask that replaces the original image pixels where one wants the glasses to show because they "are" the valid part of the mask. Very clever! It achieves the goal although it does not explain how to use copyTo to from openCV to achieve it, which is one way of interpreting what the inquiry is about.

Comment: @PabloAdames thanks for your kindly comment. There are many ways to reach to one target :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77):

> Copies the matrix to another one.
>
> The method copies the matrix data to another matrix. Before copying
>   the data, the method invokes :
>
> ```
> m.create(this->size(), this->type());
> ```
>
> so that the destination matrix
>   is reallocated if needed. While m.copyTo(m); works flawlessly, the
>   function does not handle the case of a partial overlap between the
>   source and the destination matrices.

So your data will be copied and changes won't reflect back to the original image. If you want to get rid of the white pixels in the copy you can provide a mask (the syntax might be different, doing this from memory):

```
Mat glassGray;
cvtColor(glassBGR, glassGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
glassBGR.copyTo(roiFace, glassGray != 255);
```

Your actual problem is that `roiFace` is just an alias to the memory of `faceWithGlassesNaive1`. So changes applied to `roiFace` (for example, copying new data into it) will reflect back to `faceWithGlassesNaive1`. `copyTo` is not your problem in this case, but the creation of `roiFace`.

From [Mat::operator()()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad543b6bd296ae1247032c750af4718e1):

> [...] Similarly to all of the above, the operators are O(1) operations, that 
>   is, no matrix data is copied.

Comment: This answer points to two things: 
1) `copyTo` will copy the data from the source matrix (pointed to by the `this` pointer passed in the method name as the first hidden argument) into a destination matrix designated as the first explicit argument to the method. It is a real copy of the data.
2) you can still use copyTo to create the effect of glasses on the face but a mask of the same size as the image of the face has to be provided where every pixel that is not part of the glasses is copied into the destination image while the others are passed on to the destination image.